# How to get wordpress comment form in ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have a div which class is "quick-comment" and I would like to load wordpress comment form when a user click for the `<a class="popup">Gyors komment</a>` link.

I tryed this way:

Ajax:

```
jQuery('.popup').click(function(){
          $('.quick-comment').html('Betöltés...'); // Show "loading..."
         // Do an ajax request
          $.ajax({
            url: "/getcommentform.php"
          }).done(function(data) { // data what is sent back by the php page
           $('.quick-comment').html(data); // display data
           });
       });
```

Php:

```
<?php 
require_once("wp-config.php");
comment_form(); 
?>
```

But unfortunately only thing is I get, a 404 code in chrome console, which unpossible becouse the file is there on root diretory.

I tryed opened the file in broweser, and I dosen't get anything (white scrren).
So the question is, how can I load the comment form with ajax?

Comment: If you are getting a 404 then it is most likely the url. If the issue was server side it would most likely be some kind of 500 error. You sure the file is located in the home directory of you site and not the root directory of your VM.

Comment: The file is on the `publick_html` floder, I'm sure, becouse if the url is incorrect, I can't open the php file in broweser, becouse I be redirect to 404 page.
But I can open this file, just I dosen't get any result and the crhome console sayed me for the ajax reqrest:
"404 file is not found"

Comment: @user57082 Could you solve it? I also want the comment form to be loaded via ajax